# Create wallets on website PHP

Tags: wallet, cryptography, php

I am trying to create a website that allows the deposit of cryptocurrencies (BTC / ETH / LTC) in the account, consequently I need to create a wallet at the personal registration for each of these 3 cryptocurrencies.
I would also like it to be possible to send crypto through the wallets registered on the site (p2p) and the possibility of receiving / sending crypto.

How can it be done? Is it possible to do this in PHP?

Every post I found on the forum is very old, probably a lot of things have changed.

Comment: Is this for shared hosting, or dedicated server? When I see PHP I think of shared-hosting with limited rights and permissions.

Comment: @m1xolyd1an it’s for a shared hosting, but if i need a private server to do this i could get it

Comment: As RedGrittyBlock indicates you can easily do this using the built-in JSON RPC however you will need a private server in order to install and run bitcoind.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> **Is it possible to do this in PHP?**

So far as Bitcoin is concerned, I believe it is probably possible.

For example, by looking at https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/PHP_developer_intro I can see

> The easiest way to get started is to run Bitcoin in daemon mode with which PHP communicates via local HTTP requests. A library called JSON-RPC is used to call the various functions of bitcoind, which will respond back with a JSON object.

> It is however recommended to use one of the Alternative Libraries listed below instead, since they are more sophisticated.

It goes on to briefly describe setting up PHP and the other required software and has links to other material that may be helpful.

---

ETH and LTC are off-topic on bitcoin.stackexchange.com so I won't attempt to address that aspect of your question.